# does this qualify as an "arrow function" implementation?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

Does this code represent an "arrow function"?  I copied the following spec code from an auto-genned spec file:

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyTestComponentComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

Does this code represent an "arrow function" implementation?  Can you describe what it's doing?

Comment: Yes, you wrote `() => { ... }` which is an arrow function, `this` is now bound to the `object` where it is called

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is an implementation of an "arrow function" -- often commonly referred to as a "fat-arrow function" because of the appearance (=>). Basically it's just an alternate syntax -- although there are some differences from other function implementations in terms of how it affects scope and such. In this particular case, "beforeEach()" is a function often run in Node/Mongo and test environments to ensure certain data is available prior to a subsequent function being fired -- hence the naming "beforeEach()". It's saying "before each" in regards to a collection of functions, run this first -- like I mentioned, usually to ensure certain data is available for a test or some other subsequent function to be able to run effectively.

Comment: would this typescript function also be considered an arrow function or is it more like a c# lambda, named as lambda or otherwise in typescript?:
getHeroes() {
    this._heroService.getHeroes().then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
  }